# how to make DefaultTimeBar always showing in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have two screen like youtube by using Motionlayout:

Full mode player
Mini mode
I'm using exo with DefaultTimeBar, I know this time bar will show/hide belong to controller player.
But can you support method to make DefaultTimeBar always showing, both in two mode of the above screen.
If no way, I have to create my Timebar and by manual update progress matching with player media, can I do it?

Other, can I wrap controller view in ConstraintLayout?, for aim changing size and position of controller item programmatically.
thanks.

Exoplayer Ver: 2.11.4

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution for it? I have to make same thing including Trickplay.

Comment: no man, seem be Exoplayer Controller view auto hide after 3s. so make your custom view for other aim, don't forget change progressbar with Handler.